# Animating appearing items in ListView while using ViewHolders

Tags: android, listview, animation

I am using a ListView in an Android ListFragment and also using the ViewHolder Pattern to improve the scrolling performance. The crucial part of my ListAdapter looks like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentGroup) {
    View resultView;
    Data data = dataList.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        resultView = inflateView(parentGroup);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = getViewHolder(position, resultView);
        resultView.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.fillView(data);
    } else {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        viewHolder.fillView(data);
        resultView = convertView;
    }
    resultView.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
    return resultView;
}
```

The problem is caused by the animation: If I scroll **very** slowly the new views fade in as they should. But once I scroll faster, the animation is restarted on several items that appeared before.

For example imagine a list with 20 items from those 10 are visible. If I scroll 5 items down the items 11,12,13,14 and 15 are animated each time one those new items appears. (So 11 gets animated 5 times, item 12 4 times etc.)

I think this is because the convertView is used in all of those items, so the animation does start on all of them.

Is there a possibility to only animate the appearing view while using the ViewHolders?

Thanks in advance, McFarlane

Comment: more info here : [AbsListView.OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

The problem was that I was keeping the animation as a static field somewhere to not load it from the resources every time the view was created:

```
class ViewHolder {
  static Animation anim;

  ViewHolder(Context context) {
    if (anim == null)
      anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.anim);
  }
}

//.....

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentGroup) {
    View resultView;
//  [...]
    resultView.startAnimation(anim);
    return resultView;
}
```

Looking at the [Android View source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2_r1/android/view/View.java#View.startAnimation%28android.view.animation.Animation%29) I found out that the animation is set as a field on the view when you call `startAnimation` and started with the first animation frame.

So everytime a new view was created, the same animation was started on each view it was set before. I've fixed it loading the animation directly inside the `getView` method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentGroup) {
    View resultView;
//  [...]
    resultView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.anim));
    return resultView;
}
```